# Netlogo Behaviorspace How to save data not per tick but based on reporter

Tags: memory, runtime, netlogo, behaviorspace

I have a netlogo model, for which a run takes about 15 minutes, but goes through a lot of ticks. This is because per tick, not much happens. I want to do quite a few runs in an experiment in behaviorspace. The output (only table output) will be all the output and input variables per tick. However, not all this data is relevant: it's only relevant once a day (day is variable, a run lasts 1095 days).

The result is that the model gets so slow running experiments via behaviorspace. Not only would it be nicer to have output data with just 1095 rows, it perhaps also causes the experiment to slow down tremendously.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write your own output file in a BehaviorSpace experiment. Program your code to create and open an output file that contains only the results you want.

The problem is to keep BehaviorSpace from trying to open the same output file from different model runs running on different processors, which causes a runtime error. I have tried two solutions.

1. Tell BehaviorSpace to only use one processor for the experiment. Then you can use the same output file for all model runs. If you want the output lines to include which model run it's on, use the primitive  behaviorspace-run-number.
2. Have each model run create its own output file with a unique name. Open the file using something like:
   file-open (word "Output-for-run-"  behaviorspace-run-number ".csv")
   so the output files will be named Output-for-run-1.csv etc.

(If you are not familiar with it, the CSV extension is very useful for writing output files. You can put everything you want to output on a big list, and then when the model finishes write the list into a CSV file with:
csv:to-file (word "Output-for-run-"  behaviorspace-run-number ".csv") the-big-list
)

Comment: Thank you for these tips. I'm trying option 2 now. However, the information about how to this that is available in the netlogo behaviorspace guide is not extensive. An example code there is:

 java -server -Xms16M Xmx512M -cp NetLogo.jar \
  org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace \
  --model Fire.nlogo \
  --experiment experiment2 \
  --table table-output.csv \
  --spreadsheet spreadsheet-output.csv

Using a experiment  that is already setup in the GUI behaviorspace. I can change this code with your suggestions. However, where do I put these command lines? In which file / folder?